# IOS: One navigation view controller with many different views - how should I do it?

Tags: ios, xib

I'm trying to create an IOS app that has one navigation view controller with several bar buttons, where each button changes the content of the view itself. Most of my views are custom views anyway, so I won't really see any clear previews in the storyboard anyway.

I'm thinking about creating one navigation view controller, and several NIB files to represent each view. Each NIB will have its own class with all the IBOutlets and IBActions.

Then, when a button is clicked in the navigation view controller, just switch to a new view by clearing the old one (`removeFromSuperview`), and call `loadNibNamed` to load a new view.

Does this sound reasonable or will all this deserializing be expensive in terms of CPU? Would it be better to just create different viewcontrollers in the storyboard, with segues etc, and copy those nav bar buttons to each view controller?

Comment: Have you considered a tab bar controller?

Comment: Thanks for that answer - Yes I have, but I need bar buttons both on top and bottom. Can I do that with a tab bar control?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution:

```
ViewController->
  View->
    rootViewOne
    rootViewTwo
    rootViewThree
    ...
```

upon your bar button's action,set specific rootView's hidden property to true or false:

```
self.rootViewOne.hidden = currentIndex == 0
self.rootViewTwo.hidden = currentIndex == 1
self.rootViewThree.hidden = currentIndex == 2
```

Comment: But then I would constantly have all my views in memory, wouldn't I? Wouldn't that be a waste or RAM?

Comment: You shouldn't hide or show views; rather, you should assign each view a separate view controller, and add or remove the view controllers from the parent. Apple has sample code that demonstrates this best-practices approach: State Restoration of Child View Controllers. In most cases, you don't want views still functioning when the user cannot see them. Even if they are relatively lightweight, it's unneighborly to other apps competing for the limited resources of an iPhone.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE - Embedded swapping by Sandmoose Software:

http://sandmoose.com/post/35714028270/storyboards-with-custom-container-view-controllers

Here's a snippet from the "how-it-works" section:

> The segue between ViewController and ContainerViewController is an
> embed segue. The segues between ContainerViewController and its two
> child view controllers is a custom segue. This custom segue is named
> Empty and is a subclass of UIStoryboardSegue. It contains an empty
> perform method. The ContainerViewController will take care of moving
> the child view controllers into and out of place. However, the fake
> segues are needed to create the connections in the storyboard.
>
> If you’re like me you cringe at the thought of having a fake/empty
> class like this but the benefit is that it allows us to stay firmly in
> the world of storyboard idioms without resorting to programmatically
> loading isolated storyboard scenes. It’s one tiny bit of ugliness
> which allows us to preserve the usefulness and elegance of
> storyboards. The storyboard still visually represents the scenes and
> their relationships accurately. We can still use segues to control
> what happens.

---------- Old answer below (phfffft!) ------

You pose several different questions here: one regarding custom buttons in the nav bar of a nav controller, another about assigning multiple views to the nav controller, and one about placing the view in separate XIB files, while maintaining IBOutlet connections and such.

The first one calls for a tab bar controller, which you can customize to look in whatever way you deem fit, even like a nav bar (ADC has ready-to-use sample code, "UIKit Catalog (iOS): Creating and Customizing UIKit Controls", which fits your needs).

The second can be done easily in Interface Builder by following any number of instructions freely available on YouTube, at Apple, and elsewhere on the Internet; you'll find it an extremely intuitive process. If you can drag-connect a tab bar controller to a view controller, you can intuit the rest. Otherwise, Apple has sample code for customizing the navigation or transition between views in a single view controller interface. "State Restoration of Child View Controllers" provides the best structure for what you want (just pull out the restoration-related code, and use the rest).

The third is not intuitive at all; and, as far as I know, there are only a couple of sets of instructions that exist for separating views (or other view controllers and their views) from a parent or top-level view controller. Here's one I haven't tried yet, so I'll be interested to hear how it worked for you:

http://digginginswift.com/2015/08/30/making-reusable-views-in-separate-xibs

The technique I use involves creating a storyboard with a single view controller to start, followed by a new view controller embedded in a container view for each of your intended views; then, deleting the view in each of the child view controllers, which leaves place for the views you set up in separate XIBs. They are connected by setting the File's Owner to the parent view controller. I can send you sample code, if you'd like to try a different approach than the aforementioned website offers.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your other view controller/s as child view controller.
In this way, you will have code for different views in their respective view controllers and your main/parent view controller will not be messy.

**`To add child view controller:`**

```
// Get instance of your view controller
UIViewController *childViewController = [UIViewController new];

// Add your view controller as a child view controller
[self addChildViewController:self.loginView];

// Set frame for your childViewController's view
[childViewController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];

// Add childViewController's view as a subview to your viewcontroller's view
[self.view addSubview:childViewController.view];

// Notify your main/parent controller that a child view controller is being added
[childViewController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

**`To remove child view controller:`**

```
// Notify the childViewController that it will be removed
[childViewController willMoveToParentViewController:nil];

// Remove childViewController's view
[childViewController.view removeFromSuperview];

// Remove childViewController from your main/parent view controller
[childViewController removeFromParentViewController];
```

Hope this helps.